# Counting nodes with certain attribute values in XSLT

Tags: xslt, select, variables, value-of

Suppose I have some XML like this:

```
    <section name="SampleSection">
        <item name="ScoredItem1">
            <attributes>
                <scored data_type="boolean" value="true"/>
            </attributes>
        </item>
        <item name="UnscoredItem1">
            <attributes>
                <scored data_type="boolean" value="false"/>
            </attributes>
        </item>
        <item key="(3272fbb5:22)" name="ScoredItem2">
            <attributes>
                <scored data_type="boolean" value="true"/>
            </attributes>
        </item>
    </section>
```

Now, I know, using XSLT, I can count the items that have a `scored` `attribute` like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="scoredItems" select="item/attributes/scored"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($scoredItems)"/>
```

This will give me a value of 3, of course.

Suppose I only want to count those items for which `scored` is `true`.  How do I do that using XSLT?  (This should return a value of 2 for this example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="scoredItems"
              select=
                  "item/attributes/scored[@value='true']"/>
```